# finding difficult to add values to list which has been declared as global in junit

Tags: java, list, junit, mocking

i am finding to difficult to add values to list. i did many research but none it seems working.

please find my below codes

```
public class Test(){

List <String> list=new ArrayList<>(String); // global

public Object method1(){
   // here am adding the values to list
}

String method2(){
if(list.Contains("somethig")) 
//true}
}
```

when i call method2 directly through junit, the list is empty. how can i add values to list in junit? this is where exactly am difficult to add values.

i tried below approcah but its not working. **it throws null pointer exception**

```
List<Test> obj=new ArrayList<Test>();

Test cObject=Mockito.mock(Test.class); 
cObject.list.add("something"); //getting error in this line
obj.add(cObject);
```

how can i solve the problem without refactoring my code? where am i making mistakes?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it throws null pointer exception

Comment: Could you clean up the code for Test so it at least compiles. And you should add a public method on Test to add values and not access the list directly

Comment: @Joakim i solved the issue. i have posted the solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solved this issue.

```
public class TestCases(){

@InjectMocks
Test obj=new Test();

@Test
public void list(){
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
obj.list.add("something");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection for setting custom list implementation to list. Something like:

```
    ArrayList<Object> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add("something");
    Test obj = new Test();
    Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("name_of_field");
    // need for private field access
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(obj, value);
```

Comment: its not working. but i am not getting null pointer exception when i use this approach.

Comment: i have resolve the issue. by injecting @InjectMocks on Test class.